# Why did the image in my custom TableViewCell disappear?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to customize my TableViewCell, it just fill with one image. And I tried to resize the frame of both the cell and my imageview, but when I run this program, I can't see my image on the screen.

Here is my code about the customer cell:

```
- (instancetype)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier {
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];

    if (self) {
        [self initLayout];
   }

   return self;
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

- (void)initLayout {
    self.imageView.frame = self.contentView.frame;

    [self addSubview:_image];
}

- (void)resizeWithWidth:(NSInteger)width {
    // I want the picture's width equal to the screen's, and the picture's height is 1/3 of its width
    CGRect frame = [self frame];
    frame.size.width = width;
    frame.size.height = width / 3;
    self.frame = frame;
    self.imageView.frame = frame;
}
```

And in my TableViewController, I get the cell in this way:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   IntroductViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"introductcell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

   // Configure the cell...
   if (cell) {
       cell = [[IntroductViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"introductcell"];
   }


   cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;

   if (indexPath.row == 0) {
       cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.jpeg"];
   } else if (indexPath.row == 1) {
       cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.jpeg"];
   }
   
   cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
   [cell resizeWithWidth:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds.size.width];

   return cell;
}
```

And, this is what I see when I run my program:

[image: run image]

I noticed that for each cell, there is some space. How can I remove them?

I tried to remove the line: `cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;` in cellForIndex, and I found when click the second cell, it shows the image, but I still can not see the first image in the first cell, is there some relationship?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with this line:

```
IntroductViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"introductcell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

Change it to:

```
IntroductViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"introductcell”];
```

To remove the separator line, use:

```
tableView.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
```

Answer (score 1):

I see a couple of possible problems with the code, but I can't guarantee that this will solve the problem without more context.

1) You are using 
- dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: which requires that you have called either registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier: or registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier: (the first if you are using the interface builder, the second if you defined the cell in code only).  I'm guessing you'll need the second one in your case.  Example (this would be appropriate in your TableViewController's viewDidLoad):

```
[tableView registerClass: [IntroductViewCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier: @"introductcell"];
```

Sorry if my Objective-C is off a bit, I've been using Swift exclusively for the last year or so.  If you already had this but left that part out of this question, then that's fine.

2) Get rid of this bit:

```
   if (cell) {
       cell = [[IntroductViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"introductcell"];
   }
```

First of all, you probably wanted !cell there (or something like that).  You probably didn't want to scrap the cell already there (you wanted a new one if there was none allocated, right?  Not to re-allocate if the cell retrieval was successful).  Second, it's no longer needed once you do the registerClass / 
dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: combo (in particular, the latter method will always return a valid cell).